# Php after calling bind_param(), variable returns nothing

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a method which should return some parameters like this:

```
public function registerUser($email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt)
{ 
    $sql = "insert into user_Anmeldung set email=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, user_password=?, salt=?";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    echo $email;
    echo $first_name;
    echo $last_name;
    echo $password;
    echo $salt;

    if (!$statement) {
        echo "FAIL";
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
    $statement->bind_param("sssss", $email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute(); 
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

here i call the method :

```
$result = $dao->registerUser($userEmail, $userFirstName, $userLastName, $secured_password, $salt);
```

and here i use the result :

```
if($result)
{
    $userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($userEmail);

    $returnValue["status"]="200";

    $returnValue["message"]="Successfully registered new user";  

    $returnValue["userId"] = $userDetails["user_id"];

    $returnValue["userFirstName"] = $userDetails["first_name"];

    $returnValue["userLastName"] = $userDetails["last_name"];

    $returnValue["userEmail"] = $userDetails["email"]; 

    } else {   
    $returnValue["status"]="400";

    $returnValue["message"]="Could not register user with provided information"; 
}
```

The variables `$email` etc. arent empty but the $resultValue seems empty, because after calling a method which looks if the result is empty it returns true and i cant insert the information into my database...

Comment: Where is `registerUser(` called, and how is the returned value being used?

Comment: In your code, `$returnValue` is only set if you enter the `else{}` block and the only possible value for it is boolean TRUE/FALSE. If you were to enter the `if(){}` block then you are returning void. Your code is not consistent so it makes sense that you are having issues. Also, is `$this->conn` fully accessible within your function scope?

Comment: but if it returns false it won't enter the block. Isn't it like that ? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Just a general FYI, but you're storing `salt`, which means you're not using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). You should consider switching

Comment: and it didn't changed something by changing the blocks, so this isn't the problem i think @MonkeyZeus

Comment: What does the code look like when you check the value of `$result`?

Comment: it prints nothing out.

Comment: `$resultValue` doesn't exist, and I don't see where you're defining `$returnValue` outside of your function.

Comment: why i should define it outside its just there to return the value @aynber

Comment: You're using `$returnValue` in your `if($result)` check. Anyway, if your `$returnValue`/`$result` is 0/false, then you need to use `$statement->errno` to see why the query failed.

Comment: @PaulHeinemeyer Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues currently working against you and compounding your confusion. See the code below:

This assumes you are using MySQLi.

```
public function registerUser($email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt)
{ 
    $sql = "insert into user_Anmeldung set email=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, user_password=?, salt=?";
    $prepare = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    if($prepare)
    {
        if($prepare->bind_param("sssss", $email, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $salt))
        {
            if($prepare->execute())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Execute failed<br>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Bind failed<br>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Prepare failed<br>';
    }

    echo 'MySQL error: '.$prepare->error.'<br>';

    return false;
}
```

Now feel free to do this:

```
if($dao->registerUser($userEmail, $userFirstName, $userLastName, $secured_password, $salt) === true)
{
    echo 'Registration succeeded';
}
else
{
    echo 'Registration failed';
}

die(); // go no further
```

Comment: I used your code but its still the same error message.

Comment: @PaulHeinemeyer I rewrote the error messages, there should be new messages. Please stop being so vague

Comment: he dont go into the return true block

Comment: @PaulHeinemeyer OK, do you see something that reads `MySQL error:` ?

Comment: sry, forgot to add this it says" FAILD EXEMySQL error: Duplicate entry 'email' for key 'email'"

Comment: yeah, i fixed the error thank you :). They key was the same like the parameter :)

Comment: @PaulHeinemeyer Nice, now you know how to properly debug your SQL or database issues when using PHP :-)